# Laravel: Auth Attempt failed

Tags: laravel-4

I have tried the following codes. But the auth attempt failed.

```
// validate the info, create rules for the inputs
    $rules = array(
        'email'    => 'required|email', // make sure the email is an actual email
        'password' => 'required|alphaNum|min:3' // password can only be alphanumeric and has to be greater than 3 characters
    );

    // run the validation rules on the inputs from the form
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

    // if the validator fails, redirect back to the form
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::to('login')
            ->withErrors($validator) // send back all errors to the login form
            ->withInput(Input::except('password')); // send back the input (not the password) so that we can repopulate the form
    } else {

        // create our user data for the authentication
        $userdata = array(
            'Email'     => Input::get('email'),
            'Password'  => Input::get('password')
        );

        // attempt to do the login
        if (Auth::attempt($userdata)) {
            // validation successful!
            // redirect them to the secure section or whatever
            // return Redirect::to('secure');
            // for now we'll just echo success (even though echoing in a controller is bad)
            echo 'SUCCESS!';
        } else {
            // validation not successful, send back to form
            return Redirect::to('login')->with('message', 'Login Failed');
        }

    }
```

I have the following columns in Users table.

id,
Username,
Email,
created_at,
updated_at,
Password

I have changed the table name in model. Please advice. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the convention is to make database columns lowercase. With the email column, that should not be a problem. As the documentation states, the `'email'` field is only used as an example. http://laravel.com/docs/security#authenticating-users

To make Laravel use your capitalised password column. Open your user eloquent model and change:

```
public function getAuthPassword()
{
    return $this->password;
}
```

to:

```
public function getAuthPassword()
{
    return $this->Password;
}
```

Pretty sure that'll do the trick,

Comment: I found a SOLUTION. As Bastian suggestion, I have changed all columns into lowercase. Now, it is working. :) Thanks..

Comment: I found an another issue with Auth::check() method. I did Auth::attempt() at first. Then I check the Auth::check(), but it return false. Why? Please advice.